# Is it necessary to call .off() if firebaseRef set to new value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I do:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
firebaseRef.on("value", function(dataSnapshot) { ... });
```

And then I reset `firebaseRef` like:

```
firebaseRef = new Firebase(newUrl);
```

Will the previous `.on(...)` listener be automatically removed or should I call `.off()` before setting firebaseRef to a `new Firebase(newUrl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/30541902');
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) { 
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
ref.set('1');
//ref.off();
ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/30541902');
ref.set('2');
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

So you'll need to call `off` before assigning a new value to `ref`. Luckily this is as simple as uncommenting the commented line.

Here's the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/viheso/1/edit?js,console